# Eclipse create new class take need time

Tags: java, eclipse

I am newbie in eclipse. I have problem. When i create new class, eclipse needs long time loading, its about 10-20 seconds. But when i see my friend, he can create new class without loading. I have try add more xms and xmx in the eclipse.ini but it doestn't solve the problem. FYI, I use gnome ubuntu 16, eclipse 4.5.2, RAM 4GB, Proc quad-core 2.4Ghz

How to make it faster?

You can see the loading screen shoot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKenW.png)

Comment: You say you have 4gb of RAM (I would recommend at least 8 for development), but how much of this is eclipse actually using?

Comment: You can try the solution of https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/solved-eclipse-create-new-class-slow-in-fedora/

Comment: Possibly a disk seek delay? What kind of harddrive do you have, and how full is it? If you're running on a slow, full HD and your friend is on an SSD, that could explain it.

Comment: i just realize this is eclipse's theme problem. Because when i change the theme from Dark to GTK, it solve the problem.